# Regex: select the XML messages and time stamp from the log

Tags: regex, graylog, nxlog

I am going to streaming the logs in to nxlog, i need to push xml messages in to nexlog server, To select the XML message:

```
(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.\d{3})(.*)(my sentence 1....|my sentence 2 : [\S+\s+]*>\n)(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.\d{3})
```

But I am not able to select all XML messages from logs

https://regex101.com/r/iA8qE5/5

Answer (score 0):

In your regex you have to close the alternation using `)` after:

`(Message Picked from the queue....|Response Message :`

Using a `+` inside the character class would have a different meaning and would match a plus sign literally. The plus is greedy so you have to make it non greedy using a question mark to let `[\S\s]+` not match all lines.

Update `[\S+\s+]*>\n)`

to

`)([\S\s]+?>)\n`

Your match is in the 4th capturing group.

```
(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.\d{3})(.*)(Message Picked from the queue....|Response Message : )([\S\s]+?>)\n(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.\d{3})
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dzFsX9/1)

Not that if you don't need all the capturing groups, you can also omit them and take only the first capturing group ([Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dzFsX9/2))

Answer (score 0):

it capture date from starting line, message and xml. it using `gms` flag, [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/EguHFO/1)

```
^([\d-\.\s\:]+)\s.*?-\s([\w\s:\.]+)(<\w+.*?)\n\d{4}
```

date and xml only

```
^([\d-\.\s\:]+)\s.*?(<\w+.*?)\n\d{4}
```